# ETag header not being sent from PHP

Tags: php, apache, etag

I'm running PHP 5.3.2 and Apache 2.2.14. Using `header()`, If I send "ETagx" I get the header in the response, but if I send "ETag", the correct header name, I get nothing.

`header('ETagx: "33653a-4831d8249af80"')`

works, while

`header('ETag: "33653a-4831d8249af80"')`

does not. Is there a configuration option in php.ini, or in any of the Apache configuration files that might affect this?

Comment: If you set the replace parameter to `true`, does it work then?  `header('ETag: awefawefawef', true)`

Answer (score 2):

Just tested on PHP 5.3 and Apache 2.4 and it worked for me.

Make sure that Apache don't unset your Etag like this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

FileETag None
```

Comment: I want to send the ETAGS with PHP 5.3 AND APACHE 2.0. When I check apache_request_headers() I could not get "If-Modified-Since" and "If-Modified-Since" headers. Is there any configuration needed? One addition la information, I am using https in stead http. Any idea what could be an issue.

Comment: @MANISHZOPE `apache_request_headers()` will report `If-None-Match` and `If-Modified-Since` headers, providing they exist in the request. These will obviously only be set if you have previously sent corresponding `ETag` and `Last-Modified` headers. AND you have not previously sent a `Cache-Control: no-store` header - this will block caching and the browser won't even bother sending these headers because it wants a full response. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900548/why-browser-does-not-send-if-none-match-header

Answer (score 1):

I replicated this situation when I had [Charles HTTP Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) active with the 'No Caching' option enabled - the HTTP proxy was removing the ETag and other cache-related headers.  If using a proxy to view the headers, ensure that caching is enabled for the specific request.