# Why browser does not send "If-None-Match" header?

Tags: http-headers, browser-cache, cache-control

I'm trying to download (and hopefully cache) a dynamically loaded image in PHP. Here are the headers sent and received:

Request:

```
GET /url:resource/Pomegranate/resources/images/logo.png HTTP/1.1
Host: pome.local
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/25.0.1364.160 Chrome/25.0.1364.160 Safari/537.22
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: PHPSESSID=fb8ghv9ti6v5s3ekkmvtacr9u5
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 09 Apr 2013 11:00:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.14 ZendServer/5.0
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="logo"
ETag: "1355829295"
Last-Modified: Tue, 18 Dec 2012 14:44:55 Asia/Tehran
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: image/png
```

When I reload the URL, the exact same headers are sent and received. My question is what should I send in my response to see the `If-None-Match` header in the consequent request?

NOTE: I believe these headers were doing just fine not long ago, even though I can not be sure but I think browsers are changed not to sent the `If-None-Match` header anymore (I used to see that header). I'm testing with Chrome and Firefox and both fail to send the header.

Comment: `Last-Modified: Tue, 18 Dec 2012 …` and `Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT` contradict each other a little bit, don’t you think?

Comment: That's because I want to make sure it is not cached within browser. I've just set the `Expires` equal to `Last-Modified` and got the same result.

Comment: At the very beginning of your question you say you want caching, and now you don’t?

Comment: I'm trying to implement a _reverse proxy cache system_, for that I need to make sure that browser won't cache anything locally. Instead it should ask web server for resources each time it needs them while presenting the version of its own current copy (if it has any). Browser is supposed to send resources' current version through `` but it doesn't. Which results in downloading the resources each time. But if browser succeeds to sent the resource version, PHP can tell if it is necessary to update the resource otherwise it will send "304" header which tells the browser to use its cached version.

Comment: Sorry, but it looks to me as if you are just mixing any kind of header you can think of, without any logic. You say `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache` – but expect caching to happen?

Comment: Perhaps you are right. Now that I think of it, those `Cache-Control` headers should cause the problem. The thing is that I didn't send them. They must be generated automatically. let me see if I can prevent them from being sent.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Would you please do the honor to send that as an answer (just for the record)?

Comment: This is really stupid, but I just spent 4 hours implementing this using different methods in my .NET Web Api, just to realize my chrome dev tools had caching disabled. Make sure you turn this off for testing this in Chrome!!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your response headers include `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache`; these prevent caching.

Remove those values (I think `must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0` could/should be kept – they tell the browser to check with the server if there was a change).

And I would stick with `Last-Modified` alone (if the changes to your resources can be detected using this criterion alone) – `ETag` is a more complicated thing to handle (especially if you want to deal with it in your PHP script yourself), and Google PageSpeed/YSlow advise against this one too.

Comment: It seems due to some PHP upgrade `Cache-Control` header was generate automatically without me knowing. I used PHP's [header_remove](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php) to stop any unwanted headers before I start sending my own. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For anyone else that ran into this, even after I restarted nginx after removing CacheControl, chrome still did not respect Etags. I had to close the brower tab and reopen it for it work properly.

Answer (score 47):

## Same Problem, Similar Solution

I've been trying to determine why Google Chrome won't send `If-None-Match` headers when visiting a site that I am developing. (Chrome 46.0.2490.71 m, though I'm not sure how relevant the version is.)

This is a different — though very similar — answer than the OP ultimately cited (in a comment regarding the Accepted Answer), but it addresses the same problem:

The browser does not send the `If-None-Match` header in subsequent requests "when it should" (i.e., server-side logic, via PHP or similar, has been used to send an `ETag` or `Last-Modified` header in the first response).

## Prerequisites

Using a self-signed TLS certificate, which turns the lock red in Chrome, changes Chrome's caching behavior. Before attempting to troubleshoot an issue of this nature, install the self-signed certificate in the effective Trusted Root Store, and completely restart the browser, as explained at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19102293 .

## 1st Epiphany: If-None-Match requires an ETag from the server, first

I came to realize rather quickly that Chrome (and probably most or all other browsers) won't send an `If-None-Match` header until the ***server*** **has already sent** an `ETag` header in response to a previous request. Logically, this makes perfect sense; after all, how could Chrome send `If-None-Match` when it's never been given the value?

This lead me to look at my server-side logic — particularly, how headers are sent when I want the user-agent to cache the response — in an effort to determine for what reason the `ETag` header is not being sent in response to Chrome's very first request for the resource. I had made a calculated effort to include the `ETag` header in my application logic.

I happen to be using PHP, so @Mehran's (the OP's) comment jumped-out at me (he/she says that calling `header_remove()` before sending the desired cache-related headers solves the problem).

Candidly, I was skeptical about this solution, because a) I was pretty sure that PHP wouldn't send any headers of its own by default (and it doesn't, given my configuration); and b) when I called `var_dump(headers_list());` just before setting my custom caching headers in PHP, the only header set was one that I was setting intentionally just above:

```
header('Content-type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8');
```

So, having nothing to lose, I tried calling `header_remove();` just before sending my custom headers. And much to my surprise, PHP began sending the `ETag` header all of a sudden!

## 2nd Epiphany: gzipping the response changes its hash

It then me hit me like a bag of bricks: by specifying the `Content-type` header in PHP, I was telling NGINX (the webserver I'm using) to GZIP the response once PHP hands it back to NGINX! To be clear, the `Content-type` that I was specifying was on NGINX's list of types to gzip.

For thoroughness, my NGINX GZIP settings are as follows, and PHP is wired-up to NGINX via php-fpm:

```
gzip            on;
gzip_min_length 1;
gzip_proxied    expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_types      text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript image/svg+xml;

gzip_vary on;
```

I pondered why NGINX might remove the `ETag` that I had sent in PHP when a "gzippable" content-type is specified, and came up with a now-obvious answer: because NGINX modifies the response body that PHP passes back when NGINX gzips it! This makes perfect sense; there is no point in sending the `ETag` when it's not going to match the response used to generate it. It's pretty slick that NGINX handles this scenario so intelligently.

I don't know if NGINX has always been smart enough not to compress response bodies that are *uncompressed but contain `ETag` headers*, but that seems to be what's happening here.

**UPDATE**: I found [commentary that explains NGINX's behavior in this regard](https://thinkingandcomputing.com/posts/enable-etag-nginx-resources-sent-gzip.html), which in turn cites two valuable discussions regarding this subject:

1. [NGINX forum thread discussing the behavior](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,240120,240127).
2. [Tangentially-related discussion in a project repository](https://code.google.com/archive/p/phusion-passenger/issues/903); see the comment `Posted on Jun 15, 2013 by Massive Bird`.

In the interest of preserving this valuable explanation, should it happen to disappear, I quote from `Massive Bird`'s contribution to the discussion:

> Nginx strips the Etag when gzipping a response on the fly. This is
>   according to spec, as the non-gzipped response is not byte-for-byte
>   comparable to the gzipped response.

However, NGINX's behavior in this regard might be considered slightly flawed in that the same spec

> ... also says there is a thing called weak Etags (an Etag value
>   prefixed with W/), and tells us it can be used to check if a response
>   is semantically equivalent. In that case, Nginx should not mess with
>   it. Unfortunately, that check never made it into the source tree [citation is now filled with spam, sadly]."

I'm unsure as to NGINX's current disposition in this regard, and specifically, whether or not it has added support for "weak" Etags.

## So, What's the Solution?

So, what's the solution to getting `ETag` back into the response? Do the gzipping in PHP, so that NGINX sees that the response is already compressed, and simply passes it along while leaving the `ETag` header intact:

```
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
```

Once I added this call prior to sending the headers and the response body, PHP began sending the `ETag` value with every response. Yes!

## Other Lessons Learned

Here are some interesting tidbits gleaned from my research. This information is rather handy when attempting to test a server-side caching implementation, whether in PHP or another language.

Chrome, and its Developer Tools "Net" panel, behave differently ***depending on how the request is initiated***.

If the request is "made fresh", e.g., by pressing `Ctrl+F5`, Chrome sends these headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
```

and the server responds `200 OK`.

If the request is made with only `F5`, Chrome sends these headers:

```
Pragma: no-cache
```

and the server responds `304 Not Modified`.

Lastly, if the request is made by clicking on a link to the page you're already viewing, **or** placing focus into Chrome's address bar and pressing Enter, Chrome sends these headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
```

and the server responds `200 OK (from cache)`.

While this behavior a bit confusing at first, if you don't know how it works, it's ideal behavior, because it allows one to test every possible request/response scenario very thoroughly.

Perhaps most confusing is that Chrome automatically inserts the `Cache-Control: no-cache` and `Pragma: no-cache` headers in the outgoing request **when in fact** Chrome is acquiring the responses from its cache (as evidenced in the `200 OK (from cache)` response).

This experience was rather informative for me, and I hope others find this analysis of value in the future.

Comment: Good findings, and I checked the **Disable cache** box, found there's always a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header, and lastly found the problem is that little checkbox.... sigh

Comment: thanks for the response! I also spent some time to find out why ETag is not working. As you said, I had gzipping enabled that affected my caching. Cheers!

Comment: >  there is no point in sending the ETag when it's not going to match the response used to generate it

I don't quite understand this... just because nginx gzips the content, why not send the etag for it? There's no specification around how an etag is generated - they're opaque. A browser will just send it right back in the if-none-match which nginx will just send through to the application (nginx doesn't know how the application generates etags anyway). And, the application can continue to use it's regular logic to see if the etags match.

Comment: @TomLianza I just added an explanation. Two responses that have the same ETag should be identical, byte-for-byte, and gzipping introduces entropy that compromises any such comparison. The scenario you describe refers to "weak" (AKA "semantic equivalency") validation, which NGINX doesn't consider when stripping ETags. To paraphrase NGINX developer Maxim Dounin, who explains why at the bottom of the NGINX forum thread I cited in my update to the Answer: Weak ETags are a pain to implement in this context, and the relevant caching functionality is still here with the Last-Modified cache validator.

Answer (score 8):

Posting this for future me...

I was having a similar problem, I was sending `ETag` in the response, but the HTTP client wasn't sending a `If-None-Match` header in subsequent requests (which was strange because it was the day before).

Turns out I was using `http://localhost:9000` for development (which didn't use `If-None-Match`) - by switching to `http://127.0.0.1:9000` Chrome<sup>1</sup> automatically started sending the `If-None-Match` header in requests again.

Additionally - ensure `Devtools > Network > Disable Cache [ ]` is unchecked.

**Chrome: Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

<sup>1</sup> I can't find anywhere this is documented - I'm assuming Chrome was responsible for this logic.

[image: chrome dev tools description]

Comment: Also - ensure your etag response header includes double quotes! e.g. `ETag: "<etag_value>"`

Answer (score 0):

### Similar problem

I was trying to obtain Conditional GET request with `If-None-Match` header, having supplied proper `Etag` header, but to no avail in any browser I tried.

After a lot of trial I realize that browsers treat both `GET` and `POST` to the same path as a same cache candidate. Thus having `GET` with proper `Etag` was effectively canceled with immediate "POST" to the same path with `Cache-Control:"no-cache, private"`, even though it was supplied by `X-Requested-With:"XMLHttpRequest"`.

Hope this might be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me because I had set the cache size to be too small (via Group Policy).

It didn't happen in Incognito, which is what made me realize this might be the case.

Fixing that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me due to 2 reasons:

1. My server didn't send etag response header. I updated my jetty web.xml to return etag by adding the following:

   ```
   <init-param>
       <param-name>etags</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
   ```
2. The URL I called was for xml file. When I changed it to html file, chrome started sending "if-none-match" header!

I hope it helps someone