# Etags and last-modified over https SSL?

Tags: caching, ssl, etag, last-modified, http-caching

Is it possible to use HTTP caching for conditional GET requests over a secure HTTPS connection? I've got caching working over non-secure HTTP, but when I switch to HTTPS the browser stops sending if-none-match and if-modified-since headers, so the caching breaks. I've tried various Cache-Control settings like public, max-age=3600 and whatnot, no dice.

This happens in both Safari and Chrome, so I'm assuming the SSL is breaking it somehow. Is caching not allowed over SSL?

And just to be clear, the *server* is indeed properly setting the etag and last-modified headers, but the *browser* is not sending if-none-match and if-modified-since in the request, according to the Chrome developer tools.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 15):

Figured it out! Turns out you have to have a trusted certificate. I was using my self-signed test certificate for SSL HTTPS. Adding it to my keychain and turning it green made the caching work.

Comment: Just noticed the same thing; chrome not sending etags to the server for some resources. I'm using my production SSL certificate on a test site, so it's got a big cross through it. I'll have to add a /etc/hosts entry and try it with the production domain name.

Comment: I've added my self-signed certificate to chrome, now I get green padlock, however still no If-Modified-Since with Chrome 33 (works fine with FF27) -- self-signed cert still gives message: "but does not have public audit records" -- looks like chrome does not cache in case of ANY SSL error: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110649

Comment: Oof cancel that... just restarted my chrome 33 and now all is well! So green padlock, even with "does not have public audit records" is fine.