# why we need to add app.UseResponseCaching();?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, caching, browser-cache, http-caching

after following some cache tutorials in .ASP Net Core, and performed some local tests i have some doubts related:

***Steps I did***

I added the header

```
[ResponseCache(VaryByHeader = "User-Agent", Duration = 180)]
```

Http responses has the proper header

```
cache-control: public,max-age=180
```

***Conclusion***

Despite the headers are OK, the response is never cached in any browser.

***Questions***

My first question is, **why private caches are not saving that request for that request?**
The only way to make it working is to configure in the startup :

```
 app.UseResponseCaching();
```

But as I have checked it results in an API call that return the data from the cache store in the API/server. **Second question is why browser needs to hit the API?**

Someone can explain why the browsers are no caching anything?
(I have checked that it si enabled in Developer tools)

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Not about all browsers, but for Chrome - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11245767/2501279).

Comment: As for _"My first question is, why private caches are not saving that request for that request? The only way to make it working is to configure in the startup "_ - because `UseResponseCaching` introduces middleware which caches the response in server side.

Comment: @GuruStron Yeah thats clear, but why we need API/Server Middleware to process request that should be processed in the client cache? I had checked before your first link, but in my case any browser is caching anything, is not about Chrome. I tried everything stated with no result

Comment: 1) Which browser you have tried 2) what is actual request?

Comment: 1)Chrome/Firefox 2)A simple GET to a Json with a random number inside

Comment: @GuruStron I found the solution. See the answer

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was that I was using a no-trustable SSL certificate.
When that happens, private cache stops working

See more info here: [Etags and last-modified over https SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101359/etags-and-last-modified-over-https-ssl/19102293#19102293)