# Chrome is sending Cache-control:no-cache header

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http-headers, cache-control

We have configured nginx server to add cache control header to public and expiration time to 1month. 
But when we make a request from brower, client is adding **Cache-control:no-cache** header. Because of this everytime, it is downloading the content fresh instead of serving the cached version.

how can i make to cache static files?

If I fire the request from terminal, cache-control header added by server is visible in response headers.

Check the below screenshots :
[image]
[image]

Comment: There are some related info: [If the request is "made fresh", e.g., by pressing Ctrl+F5, Chrome sends these headers:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900548/why-browser-does-not-send-if-none-match-header#:~:text=If%20the%20request%20is%20%22made%20fresh%22%2C%20e.g.%2C%20by%20pressing%20Ctrl%2BF5%2C%20Chrome%20sends%20these%20headers%3A)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You probably have the `Disable cache (while DevTools is open)` option selected in the Preferences panel of DevTools.

It's very easy to forget about it! that's what happened to me anyway. Uncheck the option and try again.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm aware of this behavior and have it unchecked yet I'm still seeing it.

Answer (score 9):

I want to add to the accepted answer that refreshing with CMD-SHIFT-R on a Mac or CTRL-SHIFT-R on Windows will also send `Cache-Control: no-cache`.