# Gin static file cache

Tags: go

Is possible to cache static files in Gin (golang)?

I tried:

```
router := gin.Default()
router.Static("/assets", "./assets")
```

But I get a response with status code 200 whenever I refresh the page. I assume it should be 304 (or similar), but https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin has no mention about HTTP caching (at least for now).

How can I handle static file caching in gin?

Answer (score 3):

In case you were using Chrome, this might be the cause:

> You probably have the Disable cache (while DevTools is open) option selected in the Preferences panel of DevTools.
>   [Chrome is sending Cache-control:no-cache header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719038/chrome-is-sending-cache-controlno-cache-header)

[image]